# MySql query to pull the original message but not the linked messages

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP and MySQL to create messaging script, what i need to do is display the original messages in inbox and when the specific message is clicked only then show the chain of messages linked with the original message. The original message should be displayed for the person who sent it and the person who received it.

This is what i am inserting in my table

```
message_id
to_user_id
from_user_id
subject
message
original_message_id
```

when a new message is initiated the `original_message_id` is blank but whoever replies to this message, the column  `original_message_id` then stores the same id as `message_id` to keep track of conversation.

Now to test this lets assume there are two user_ids in system 1 and 2. I sent the new message to `to_user_id` 2 from `from_user_id` 1 and the reply was sent as well from `from_user_id` 1 to `to_user_id` 2.

I have entries in my table without any problem. So far this is working correct. What i am stuck at is when i display the new message in inbox it displays two records the original message the the reply as well and this is the query i am using, please let me know what is wrong with this query

```
`SELECT * FROM tbl_messages WHERE `to_user_id` = '1' OR `from_user_id` = '1' AND original_id IS NULL`
```

Reason i am using both `to_user_id` and `from_user_id` so the system displays the original received message for the recipient and sent message for the sender

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AND` operator has higher precedence than `OR`, so you need to add parentheses to get the intended parse.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_messages WHERE (`to_user_id` = '1' OR `from_user_id` = '1') AND original_id IS NULL
```